# Value Converter not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

A bit confused here, I seem to have followed the steps that would allow me to make use of value converters.

I have my converter defined with a key, as such:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage Title="Article"
                 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.Controls;assembly=XamarinMobile"
                 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.Converters;assembly=XamarinMobile"
                 x:Class="XamarinMobile.ArticlePage">
      <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <converters:FontSizeConverter x:Key="FontSizeMapper"></converters:FontSizeConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ContentPage.Resources>
```

I then make use of my converter in my XAML, as such:

```
          <ContentView Padding="10,-10,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <StackLayout>
              <Label x:Name="LabelAuthor" FontSize="{Binding 20, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeMapper}, ConverterParameter=20}" />
              <Label x:Name="LabelPublishDate" FontSize="{Binding 10, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeMapper}, ConverterParameter=10}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ContentView>
```

And here is my actual converter code:

```
namespace XamarinMobile.Converters
{
    public class FontSizeConverter : Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value is double)
            {
                return App.NormalizeFontSize((double)value);
            } else
            {
                return value;
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I then put a break point in my value converter, but it never hits. Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? I'm pretty sure I followed the directions to a tee.

Comment: You're 'binding' to a static value (with `Binding 20`), I reckon you should be binding a property in your `BindingContext` object

Comment: If i understood correctly, that's how you pass the value parameter. Which I have varying values I want to pass, making a property for each doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: No, you should bind to a property which has a value, only it is not the value that is useable as a FontSize in your case. So you need a converter to convert the value in the property to a FontSize. Imagine you bind to a property which contains a font-size in string like `"Twenty"`. The `FontSize` property will not understand `"Twenty"` so you need to convert it with a converter. You bind to the property which contains the string value and convert it through a converter. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I bind it to a property when I'm using it in XAML? Are you saying the value needs to be a string? I don't understand that. I completely understand that fontsize doesn't understand "Twenty" which is why I'm passing a double (really an integer, but can be treated as a double). The issue I'm having is, that it's not even going to my value converter.

Comment: I would use an attached property for this

Comment: Hmm.. okay. Can you provide an example (and if it works, obviously I'd mark your answer as correct :D)? Also, would this explain why my breakpoint in my converter isn't firing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your breakpoint isn't being hit due to what [Gerald Versluis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961221/value-converter-not-working-in-xamarin#comment71101521_41961221) said.  Your binding is broken.  What your binding is saying is: Bind to the property named "10" on the `BindingContext`, and use the `Converter` FontSizeMapper, passing it an extra `ConverterParameter` of 10.  "10" isn't a valid property name, so the binding is breaking.  If you look in your logs, you should see a message similar to: "Binding: '10' property not found on ..."

One way to fix it would be to remove the "Path" you're trying to bind to and only make use of the `ConverterParameter` (assuming you don't need to bind to any real properties):

```
FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FontSizeMapper}, ConverterParameter=20}"
```

Note that you'll need to make use of the `parameter` in the converter, rather than the `value` (eg. `if (parameter is double)`).

If you don't need to bind to any properties, another way to fix it would be to use a custom markup extension instead.

```
[ContentProperty("FontSize")]
public class FontSizeMapperExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public double FontSize { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return App.NormalizeFontSize(FontSize);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it in your XAML like:

```
FontSize="{converters:FontSizeMapper FontSize=10}
```

**Edit**

An example of binding to a property on an object:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public double VMFontSize { get; set; }
}

public partial class ArticlePage : ContentPage
{
    public ArticlePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // NOTE: You'd probably get your view-model another way
        var viewModel = new YourViewModel { VMFontSize = 10 };
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Now that your view-model is set as the binding context, you can set the binding like:

```
FontSize="{Binding VMFontSize, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeMapper}}"
```

What this says is: Bind the FontSize property on the label to the VMFontSize property on the current `BindingContext` (your view-model), using the converter to map between the view-model's VMFontSize and the Label's FontSize. I left the `ConverterParameter` off here as it isn't really needed in this example, but you could pass one if you need it.

Comment: `If you don't need to bind to any properties, another way to fix it would be to use a custom markup extension instead.` I want to do this the right way. Can you show me how to bind it to a property? I'm just a little confused how to do that when my markup is in XAML. Or maybe I'm completely just wrong, which is why I want to see an example. But thanks, this helped a lot.

Comment: If you want to bind to a property whose value is sent to your converter, you would need to do: `FontSize="{Binding YourPropertyName, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeMapper}, ConverterParameter=20}"`.  That property needs to exist on whatever is set as your page's `BindingContext`.  Note that you can still pass an additional `ConverterParameter` even when binding to a property.  I'll add a more thorough example if you still need one.  Just let me know!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this a different way, using a custom attached property, see more on attached properties here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/

Here is a sample for your scenario, first we need to define an attached property, it can be in any class, I called mine FontHelper

```
namespace App23
{
    public static class FontHelper
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
            BindableProperty.CreateAttached("FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(FontHelper), 0d, propertyChanging:OnPropertyChanging);

        public static bool GetFontSize(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (bool)view.GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetFontSize(BindableObject view, bool value)
        {
            view.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanging(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (bindable is Label)
            {
                var label = bindable as Label;
                double fontSize = (double)newValue;
                // normalize your font size here
                label.FontSize = fontSize;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it in XAML, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App23"
             x:Class="App23.MainPage">

  <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" local:FontHelper.FontSize="50"/>

</ContentPage>
```